# How can I find the version of Scala installed in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

The question is how can I find the version of the Scala module installed in the Eclipse IDE?
I know I've installed 2.9.xxx something, but I'd like to keep tracking the version number
in case of future updates in order to, for example, look up the right API manual.

Or is there a general way to see the versions of the installed plugins in Eclipse IDE?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Help->About Eclipse->[scala-ide.org Button]->Plugin-Details: There you can see the plugin "Scala Library for Eclipse" with the Scala version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Christian! Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can check the installed plugins versions at Help menu | About Eclipse | Installation details | Plug-ins.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and precise answer, Kristof! ;)