# Iterator<String> not accepted after re-setting the build path

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, buildpath

I have a Spark streaming app and I have re-setted the build path, in order to make it cleaner.
After I re-imported all the jar files, I get this error I've never had before:
[image]
How is it possible? How can I solve this?

```
static FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, String> sentimentFunc = new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, String>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @Override
        public Iterator<String> call(Tuple2<String, String> x) throws Exception {
            List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(x._2==null){
                output.add("ERR");
                return output.iterator();
            }
            boolean like = false, sad = false, angry = false, hilarious = false, neutral = false;
            boolean [] sentiments = {like, angry, sad, hilarious, neutral};
            sentiments = checkEmojis(x, sentiments);
            if(checkSentiment(sentiments)){
                output.add(setSentiment(sentiments));
                return output.iterator();
            }

            sentiments = checkText(x, sentiments);
            output.add(setSentiment(sentiments));
            return output.iterator();
        }

  };
```

Comment: There is an incompatibility between the method signature and the "return" statement in the method. But you haven't shown the latter so... Also please paste code as text, not as an image.

Comment: ok I have updated the question. The code was working fine just five mins ago, so I don't see how it's possible an incompatibility

Comment: my mistake, now is the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark 1.x, the return type of `call` for [`FlatMapFunction`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html) is `Iterable`.

In Spark 2.x, the return type of `call` for [`FlatMapFunction`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html) has been changed to `Iterator`.

It seems that when you reset your build path, you changed it to point to spark 1.x instead of 2.x, thus invalidating all your flatmap functions.

Comment: I've got this identical issue too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373228/error-with-spark-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-conformslscala-predefles
Changing the pom isn't enough. How can I solve this?